# Swift Progress View animation makes the bar go further than 100%

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, animatewithduration

When using animations for the ProgressView, it works completely fine if I let the animation run out but if I try to run this code again while the animation is still going, it will add 100% to the current bar and make it go through the bar. Images should explain the situation in a more logical sense.

Progress starts at 1.0 (100%):

[image]

Progress is half-way through:

[image: Progress is half-way through]

The code was ran again, resulting in the progress going above 100%, although it uses the correct amount of time to finish.

[image: The code was ran again, resulting in the progress going above 100%, although it uses the correct amount of time to finish.]

Here's the code used:

```
self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: false)
        
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState, .allowUserInteraction], animations: { [unowned self] in
    self.progressView.setProgress(0, animated: true)
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible something in the rest of the code you are running (while setting up the next question) is inadvertently changing the frame or constraints on the progressView?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some quick research...

Turns out `UIProgressView` needs a little special effort to stop the current animation. See if this does the job for you:

```
    // stop any current animation
    self.progressView.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeAllAnimations() }

    // reset progressView to 100%
    self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: false)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        // set progressView to 0%, with animated set to false
        self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
        // 10-second animation changing from 100% to 0%
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { [unowned self] in
            self.progressView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

Comment: it works good for all values, excepts 0 - which there its vanish without animation...

Answer (score 9):

The `setProgress(_:animated:)` method already handles the animation for you. When the `animated` parameter is set to `true`, the progress change will be animated.

Try without the animation block :

```
self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: false)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
}
```

Also make sure this is not an autolayout issue. Check your constraints on the progress view and make sure its width is properly constrained.